# Casting Generic base object to derived type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting

What is the correct way to cast a base class that is using generics back to its derived type?

I have the following object implemented.

Note that the "Save" method is calling the "WriteSettings" method here (takes in a BaseSettings object)

```
public class Settings1
{
    public string strData;
}

public class BaseSettings<T>
{
    T settings;
    public iSettingsDestination Destination;

    public bool Save()
    {
        return Destination.WriteSettings(this);
    }
}

public class Settings1Manager : BaseSettings<Settings1>
{
    public bool DoSomething()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have created an interface iSettingsDestination that will always use the base class (BaseSettings) to pass the object.  Classes derived from iSettingsDestination can choose which object types to handle.
I want to be able to pass this object as it's base type into a method, determine the derived type, and reverse the cast. (see below)  I receive a compile error when trying to cast back to the derived type.

```
public interface iSettingsDestination
{
    bool WriteSettings<T>(BaseSettings<T> settings);
}

public class FileDestination : iSettingsDestination
{
    bool WriteSettings1ManagerToFile(Settings1Manager settings)
    {
        // write to file
        return true;
    }

    bool WriteSettings<T>(BaseSettings<T> settings)
    {
        if (typeof(Settings1Manager).IsAssignableFrom(settings.GetType()))
        {
            // generates error
            // Cannot convert type 'BaseSettings<T>' to 'Settings1Manager'
            return WriteSettings1ManagerToNetwork((Settings1Manager)settings);
        }

        // unhandled object type
        return false;
    }

}
```

I want to be able to call the code like below.  For the example here, I only show 1 type of "Destination" and "Settings" but you can imagine that there are many different types that can be used here.

```
    void main()
    {
        Settings1Manager settings1 = new Settings1Manager();
        settings1.Destination = new FileDestination();
        settings1.Save(); // saves to a file
    }
```

I am able to do this with other base classes but it seems that using generics here causes issues.

1) How can I correctly make the cast back to the derived type in the call WriteSettings1ManagerToNetwork((Settings1Manager)settings);

2) Does anyone see any issues blatant misuse of the Generics/interface/etc logic here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference declared as `BaseSettings<T>` *may or may not* refer to an actual instance of `Settings1Manager`. That's how inheritance works. In fact though, what you're doing is casting a base type reference that's actually referring to an object that you've just confirmed actually *is* of the derived type.

`settings as Settings1Manager` will compile, because `as` will just return `null` if the cast fails. You and I know that particular cast won't fail, but the compiler just follows its rules.

```
if (typeof(Settings1Manager).IsAssignableFrom(settings.GetType()))
{
    return WriteSettings1ManagerToNetwork(settings as Settings1Manager);
}
```

This works too, because you can cast anything to `object` and you can cast `object` to anything. But you don't want people seeing your name on code that looks like this.

```
return WriteSettings1ManagerToFile((Settings1Manager)(object)settings);
```